# Define a meromorphic function $F$ on $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Define a meromorphic function $F$ on $\mathbb C$ such that $\displaystyle F(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)} $ when $\Im (z)>0$.

That is I want to define $F(z)$ in $\Im(z)\le 0$ in such a way that $F$ is entire. But I'm unable to start.

Please give hint.

Comment: It might be hard to do that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no entire function that coincides with $\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)}$ for numbers with positive imaginary part.

An entire function is continuous, yet $\lim_{z \to 2} F(z)$ cannot exist.

If you just want a meromorphic function on the entire plane, define it via that original formula, except for the poles at $1$ and $2$.